# Why does a recurrence of $T(n - 1) + T(n - 2)$ yield something in $\Omega(2^{\frac{n}{2}})$?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I am trying to analyze the running time of a bad implementation of generating the $n$th member of the fibonacci sequence (which requires generating the previous 2 values from the bottom up).

Why does this algorithm have a time complexity of $\Omega(2^{\frac{n}{2}})$? Where does the exponent come from?

Comment: Try writing a recurrence relation expressing the running time and solve it.

Comment: Just to be clear, "time complexity of _at least_" is talking about the lower bound. Here it means that the lower bound is of $O(2^{n/2})$, which basically means that $T(n) \in \Omega(2^{n/2})$. The answers below demonstrate this fact.

Comment: "the lower bound is of $O(\\_)$" resp "at least $O(\\_)$" -- that does not make much sense. The lower bound needs to be in $\Omega(\\_)$, too. See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use).

Comment: @Raphael Oh I agree it is an abuse of the notation, and should not be used, but unfortunately I have seen it being used. When saying $f(n)$ is _atleast_ $O(g(n))$, what is being  implied (and hence the abuse) is that $g(n)$ is a _tight_ upper bound on some $h(n)$, and that $f(n)$ is $\Omega(h(n))$, thereby also implying $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$.

Comment: @Raphael But yeah, your edit of the question seems the right way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on Reza's answer, every recurrence of the form $T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)$, with arbitrary initial values, has a solution of the form
$$ T(n) = A \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n + B \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n, $$
for some $A,B$. Note that $|(1-\sqrt{5})/2| < 1$, and so the second term tends to zero as $n \longrightarrow \infty$. Assuming that $T(n)$ tends to infinity, $A > 0$ and so
$$ T(n) = \Theta\left( \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n \right). $$
Now $(1+\sqrt{5})/2 > \sqrt{2}$, and so $T(n) = \Omega(2^{n/2})$.

---

Edit: This part is also covered in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3135/98) (see under "A Shortcut").

More generally, for a recurrence of the form $T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i T(n-i)$, let
$$ P(t) = t^n - \sum_{i=1}^k a_i t^{n-i}. $$
If $P$ has no repeated roots and the (possibly complex) roots are $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$, then the solution is always of the form
$$ T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k A_i \lambda_i^n. $$
If it does have repeated roots, say the roots are $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_l$ with multiplicities $m_1,\ldots,m_l$, then the solution is always of the form
$$ T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^l A_i(n) \lambda_i^n, $$
where $A_i$ is a (possibly complex) polynomial of degree smaller than $m_i$.

In our case, $P(t) = t^2-t-1$ has no repeated roots, and the two roots are $(1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$.

The $A_i$s depend on the initial values, and can be found by solving linear equations. For example, suppose we are given $T(0)$ and $T(1)$ for our recurrence. Then we can find $A,B$ by solving the system
$$
\begin{align*}
T(0) &= A + B, \\
T(1) &= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} A + \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} B.
\end{align*}
$$
This works even in the case of repeated roots, and $k$ initial values always suffice. Assuming $a_k \neq 0$, $k$ initial values are also necessary.

Comment: I think the second part of your answer has been covered [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3135/98) ("A Shortcut"). If not, you should probably add an answer there with the general idea.

Answer (score 4):

It's not $O(2^{n\over 2})$ is $\Theta(\phi^n)$ which doesn't belong to $O(2^{n\over 2})$ but you can say belongs to $\Omega(2^{n\over 2})$ or belongs to $O(2^n)$ (and saadtaame showed this in his answer), So be careful about abuse of notations. But why is $\Theta(\phi^n)$? as a student of CS you should try to solve it yourself but if you tried and you couldn't show it, show us your try and we can help you.

Oh Seems I forgot to say why is in $\Omega(2^{n\over 2})$ (and I think your main question was this, or totally you were wrong):
$T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2) \gt 2T(n-2)$ and this results: $T(n) > 2^{n\over 2}T(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The running time of the naive solution is: $$T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2) \lt 2T(n-1)$$
Now, $$2T(n-1)=2(2T(n-2))=2(2(2T(n-3)))=\dots=2^kT(n-k)=\dots=2^nT(0)=O(2^n)$$

The base case takes time $T(0)=\Theta(1)$. So that's where the exponent is coming from. This result is an upper bound; you can obtain a tighter bound if you solve the recurrence using generating functions for example.

Comment: Again, $O(2^n)$ is *not* the end result we need; we need $\Omega$.

Comment: This can be 'flipped around' to give the result the OP is after, though - I'll write it up in a moment here.

Answer (score 1):

you can find for **Every linear recurrence with constant coefficients** a closed form. (See the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)) the [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) numbers have a closed-form solution as (the approximation is for large ns):

$F_n \times \sqrt{5} ={ \left( \frac { 1+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ n }-{ \left( \frac { 1-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ n } \simeq { \left( \frac { 1+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ n } \simeq (1.6180..)^n \simeq 2.89^{n/2} $

or more formaly $ F_n \in\Omega (2^{n/2})$.

You can find more in [Conceret Mathematics](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Graham%20-%20Knuth%20-%20Patashnik%20-%20%20Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf), by Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth and
Oren Patashnik, chapter 6 : Special Numbers.

Comment: That's not helping. You are confusing the OP.

Comment: @saadtaame: This is the exact way of computing Fibonacci or any constant coefficient recursive relation. It could be found in any cobinatorial book, no confusion at all !. I think this is nessasary for any computer science student to know.

Comment: What does "is at least $O(2^{n/2})$" mean? please use mathematical definitions and validate your sentence with big-oh definition.

Comment: "at least $O(\dots)$" not a meaningful statement, as $1 \in O(f)$ for most functions $f$ that pop up in algorithm analysis.